# Kernel32.INSTANCE.ReadProcessMemory cannot be found in JNA

Tags: java, jna, kernel32

```
       import com.sun.jna.Native;
       import com.sun.jna.Memory;
       import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
       import com.sun.jna.ptr.*;
       import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
       import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
       import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
       import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
       import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.*;


public class apples {


       public static void main(String[] args) {

           IntByReference pid = new IntByReference();
           int offset = 0x7AF5DBDC;
           int buffer = 32;
           Memory output = new Memory(buffer);

HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow("notepad", null);   
    if (hwnd != null)
    {
    System.out.println("i got the handle");
    User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pid);
    System.out.println("PID is " + pid.getValue());
    WinNT.HANDLE hProc =  Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(0, false, pid.getValue());

    Output: 
    i got the handle
    PID is 752
```

Next, I want to use Kernel32.INSTANCE.ReadProcessMemory();

However, I am unable to find the function within Kernel32. Was this function removed? If so, is there any other way to do ReadProcessMemory?

I am using Java and using JNA Lib.

Thank you.

Comment: If it *is* missing, you can always extend the interface and define your own.

Answer (score 1):

The question was originally asked in 2012. The `ReadProcessMemory` function was added to the `jna.platform.win32.Kernel32` interface [on Jun 29 2014](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/commit/b0546cda7601ee85936a82d945dc2edfc78aa254), meaning that the function was simply not mapped yet at the time of asking.

JNA versions 4.2.0 and above ship with the function included.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to define the Kernel32 instance before calling it's functions.

```
Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary(Kernel32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
int memValue = kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(WinNT.HANDLE, pointer, pointer, int, IntByReference);
```